# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Hiding Nav Links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, navbar

I am having trouble with my drop down menu on mobile devices. I am using Twitter Bootstrap and when I open the menu on a mobile device it is off to the right and therefore hard to see the nav links. I would like to break it down to another line and have the menu items on the left.

I have tried a number of things and have located the correct id/class selectors but Im not sure how to break it down to another line.

Here is the Media Query I am editing

```
    /** Mobile **/
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px), only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {

#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 .navbar-nav .pages {



}
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="pages"><a href="#section2">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="pages"><a href="#section3">Free Trial</a>    </li>
                    <li class="pages"><a href="#section3">Subscribe</a></li>
                    <li class="pages"><a href="#section4">Testimonials</a>    </li>
                    <li class="pages"><a href="#section5">Who</a></li>
                    <li class="pages"><a href="#section6">FAQ</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
```

I'm not trying to promote my site but if its easier to see you can go to growthengine.co to see what I mean with the menu.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: why don't you use <.br/>?

Answer (score 0):

Paul, First off could you just try doing this please.

At the end of your page you have the bootstrap js file.
Replace it with this ...

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
```

When I did this your menu starts to work as you intended.

**Edit:**
When I linked to your custom css the problem came back.
So the cause is in there, your custom css code.
In the top left corner you have this...
`<h1><a href="#top">Growth <span id="h1highlight">ENGINE</a></span></h1>`
If you comment this out then your menu starts to work again.

Look at sorting this out to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. 

I tried this and on my iphone 6+ it didn't change unfortunately.

Could it be looking right on a smaller device, but still not be correct on an iphone6+?

Comment: Hi, I just added to my post , take a look now.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a life saver as the website is "launching" today. Thanks again. I would upvote but I don't have upvoting privileges yet

Comment: That's great, can I suggest somethings I noticed in the code. The image of the rocket is wide to the left being orange and the rocket is to the right. When you resize the rocket disappears.  if you add this to your css `background-image: url("http://growthengine.co/img/rocket7.png");
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;` it will keep the rocket in view. but at a certain screen size you may need to change the text color as part of the rocket is white.

Comment: Also... You have two `meta name="viewport"` . and you have two `bootstrap.js` scripts, one at the top of the page and one at the bottom.  I hope that helps.